# How does loadByCode() works in magento

Tags: magento

How does `loadByCode()` works? I have been adding a module to my new project and don't know how to use model uses `loadByCode` method with a given code.

Comment: You should additionally provide the given error code. With that information we can't do very much.

Comment: I just wanted to know how loadByCode() works in case it is any standard function , and it turns out that its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at magento model class it extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` which intern extends `Varien_Object`.

The class `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` has function like `getId()`, `load()`, `save()`, `delete()` etc...

`Mysql4` resource files are used to perform database queries on tables.

Suppose we have the file `Keyur_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test` resource file.

```
<?php
class Keyur_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {   
        $this->_init('test/test', 'test_id');
    }
    public function loadByField($field,$value){
        $table = $this->getMainTable();
        $where = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("$field = ?", $value);
        $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from($table,array('test_id'))->where($where);
        $id = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchOne($sql);
        return $id;
    }
}
```

And here is the model file `Keyur_Test_Model_Test`

```
<?php
class Keyur_Test_Model_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('test/test');
    }
    public function loadByField($field,$value){
        $id = $this->getResource()->loadByField($field,$value);
        $this->load($id);
    }
}
```

In this file there are many new functions which have been used. Let’s take them one by one. In our model file, we have used this function -

```
$id = $this->getResource()->loadByField($field,$value);
```

`$this->getResource()` function returns the resource model’s object. So we are simply calling the `loadyByField($field,$value)` function in the resource model.

`getTable()` function

Now in our Mysql4 file, in the `loadByField()` function we have used `$table = $this->getMainTable();` .This function returns the table name of the current model, i.e the one defined in the class’s constructor. If you want to get table name of another sql table in magento, we need to the `getTable()` call e.g

```
$table = $this->getTable(‘newsletter/subscribe’);
```

`_getReadAdapter()` function

Next we have:
 `$where = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto(“$field = ?”, $value);`

Here the first function too see is the `$this->_getReadAdapter()` function. This function return an object which has function to perform database query, like `fetch()`, `fetchAll()`, `query()`, etc.

`_quoteInfo()` function

Another function we have used is `quoteInto()`: This function is used to create our where conditions.

In this the actual value is substituted into the question mark we have written. For e.g `$this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto(“user_id = ?”, 3);` translates to “user_id = 3″.

Another frequently used variation of `quoteInfo()` is

```
$where = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("$field IN(?)", array(1,2,3));
```

this translates to “`field in (1,2,3)`”

Getting deeper into the `quoteInto()` function: If we have multiple where conditions we can use

```
$where = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("$field = ? AND ", $value).$this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("$field1 = ? OR ", $value1).$this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("$field2 = ?", $value2);
```

Continuing on the loadByField function in our resource model, next we have

```
$select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from($table,array(‘test_id’))->where($where);
```

Here we have created the select query using the `select()`, and on that called the from() function.

`from()` function

The `from()` function takes many different parameters, if you want to fire a simple select * query, you need to only pass the table name like `from($table)`.

But right now, I wanted to select just a single column that is test_id, so I passed an array with column name to

```
 select. i.e array(‘test_id’).
```

If we want to select multiple column, we need to `array(‘test_id’,’col1’,’col2’)`.

This will create a sql like “select test_id,col1,col2 from $table”.

But support we want a sql query like “select test_id as id,col1 as column1 from $table” , i would call -

```
from($table,array('id'=>'test_id','column1'=>'col1'));
```

Comment: i was not looking for this,but anyways thanks. If you know any tutorial site for magento please-2 mention that.

Comment: @TaushifAli not looking for this means ?

Comment: i really appreciate what u did,it is a really good example and well explained.But the thing on which i am working does not use mysql4.I am newbie in this field and simply wanted to know about loadByCode().But i figured out that it is not any standard function.Thanks and sorry for wasting your time :)